# Telegram bot that I wrote in Python not functioning correctly

Tags: python, telegram-bot

why is the Telegram bot that I wrote in Python not functioning correctly? The bot can send the user's message to the admin, but it does not send the admin's message to the user.

```
import nest_asyncio
from telegram import Update, Message
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackContext

import logging

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Apply nest_asyncio to allow the bot to run in environments like Jupyter notebooks
nest_asyncio.apply()

# Replace 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN' with the token you received from BotFather
YOUR_BOT_TOKEN = ''
# Replace 'ADMIN_CHAT_ID' with the chat ID of the admin
ADMIN_CHAT_ID = ''

# Dictionary to store user messages with message ID as the key
user_messages = {}

async def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_text('Hello! I am your messenger bot.')

async def handle_user_message(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    # Store the user's message with message ID as the key
    user_messages[update.message.message_id] = (update.effective_chat.id, update.message.text)
    # Notify the admin with the message content and a reference to the message ID
    await context.bot.forward_message(chat_id=ADMIN_CHAT_ID,
                                      from_chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                                      message_id=update.message.message_id)
async def handle_admin_reply(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    # Check if the admin's message is a reply to a forwarded message
    if update.message.reply_to_message and update.message.reply_to_message.forward_from:
        # Send the admin's reply to the original user
        await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.reply_to_message.forward_from.id,
                                       text=update.message.text)

def main() -> None:
    application = Application.builder().token(YOUR_BOT_TOKEN).build()

    # Handlers
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND & filters.ChatType.PRIVATE, handle_user_message))
    application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & filters.ChatType.PRIVATE & filters.REPLY, handle_admin_reply))

    # Run the bot
    application.run_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

this code should send the message that admin sent for bot to user that admin reply to it but it doesnt do that.